# Оптимизация .h файлов в проекте

Tags: оптимизация, c++

В связи с ростом проекта озадачился оптимизацией.
Файлов много, в ручную не хочется.
Нашел вот такую забавную штуку: [include-what-you-use](https://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/)
Все бы хорошо, но как то не очень здорово она компилируется на моем маке :)

Пока вожусь с ее настройкой, может кто поделится своим опытом?

Comment: а прекомпиляцию хедеров уже пробовали?
Кстати, очень сильно помогают ещё многопоточная компиляция (make умеет, с параметром -j 4 для 4 ядерного), больше ОЗУ (8 гиг минимум и диск в оперативке) и, конечно же, ssd.

Comment: Это уже проходили :)
Тем не менее, если собирать проект с нуля, выходит больше часа.

ЗЫ:
>> make умеет, с параметром -j 4 для 4 ядерного.
На самом деле для 4х ядерного оптимальныей 5 потоков, так в man make сказано.

Comment: да, знаю о 5 для 4 ядерного. Но у меня получалось как раз при 4 хорошо. Может такая фаза Луны была.

А о том, что оно уже час собирается - как раз и нужно писать.  ssd/оперативку тоже проходили?

Comment: На моей машине стоит 8Гб, и HDD, проц i5 2.5Gh
Но дело не в железе, морально давит что непорядок в .h

* на билд сервере 12 ядер, 32Гб ОЗУ и ssd, там на порядок быстрее. Но на то он и билд сервер :)

Comment: а у Вас на порядок - это в 2 раза (тогда вполне логично получается и по скорости тоже), или в 10 раз? В этом случае как то странно. Попробуйте просто для начала внешний ssd (правда главное его не подлкючить по медленному интерфейсу).

А ещё очень сильно могут тормозить всякие template. Некоторые умудряются в них делать кучу расчетов. А это не так дешево, как кажется.

Из своего опыта. Один и тот же проект на более слабом декстопе (i3 cpu)компилиться в несколько раз быстрее, чем на хорошем ноуте (i7, ssd, более быстрая память). А причина в том, что на ноуте винда(mingw), на декстопе - linux.

Comment: У меня завелась тулза " include-what-you-use" о которой писал выше.
За пол часа прошлась по 13% файлов :)

смущает что она только ничего не пишет, хотя (наверное) должна, как мне казалось.
Когда доработает, расскажу что и как.

------

Что касается билд сервера, он минут за 20-25 отрабатывает примерно. точные цифры не скажу сейчас.

При этом проц загружается всего немного. Можно еще 3-4 проекта одновременно запускать без труда

Comment: @ikonnov, а какая доля исходного кода у Вас в хидерах? Если много инлайн-кода, это не есть хорошо. В таком случае, лучше вынести реализацию этих модулей в `cpp` это позволит компилировать их в одном экземпляре. Если "проходили", то скорее всего, не стоял бы вопрос о ".h". Если не устроит результат, можно отказаться от `precompiled header` и включать в каждый `cpp` индивидуальный(минимальный) набор хидеров. Это так же сократит нагрузку на компилятор.  
 --  
Простой проверкой эффективности многопоточной компиляции для SMP при этом будет наличие равномерной нагрузки на все процессоры.

Comment: >При этом проц загружается всего немного. Можно еще 3-4 проекта одновременно запускать без труда

По всей видимости, этот комментарий я не увидел. Но как раз такое поведение говорит о том. что у Вас мало исходного кода в `cpp`. Они-то как раз и параллелятся. Вытаскивайте код из инлайна.

Answer (score 1):

Пришел к выводу что лучше все делать руками :)

После того как запустил "include-what-you-use" получил коммит с тысячами insert/delete.
На тестовом проекте, который собирался чуть больше 9 минут (Apple LLVM), получил профита аж 
почти 30 секунд :)

Тулзу запускал в базовой комплектации, без кастомных настроек.

Полагаю это хороший инструмент, если им пользоваться часто, скажем раз в неделю лид будет вырезать ненужное. Но не думаю что он поможет решить проблему глобально.